# Помогите с кодом php

Tags: php, алгоритм, математика

У меня есть таблица, которая называется coords, в которой находятся координаты маршрутов в таком виде. Моя задача вывести те маршруты которые находятся близко к данному. Я думаю это сделать следующим образом- взять первые и последние координаты и сравнить их с последней и первой координатой заданного маршрута. Взять координату заданного маршрута как центр окружности радиусом 300 м,  если кто-то попадает в эту окружность, то выводить этот маршрут в списке.

```
[{"lon":"30.4585","lat":"50.50654"},{"lon":"30.45833","lat":"50.50699"},{"lon":"30.45804","lat":"50.50778"},{"lon":"30.45784","lat":"50.50834"},{"lon":"30.45763","lat":"50.50901"},{"lon":"30.45763","lat":"50.50901"},{"lon":"30.45822","lat":"50.50907"},{"lon":"30.45878","lat":"50.50912"},{"lon":"30.46052","lat":"50.50933"},{"lon":"30.46209","lat":"50.50946"},{"lon":"30.46243","lat":"50.50949"},{"lon":"30.46243","lat":"50.50949"},{"lon":"30.46294","lat":"50.50859"},{"lon":"30.46355","lat":"50.50755"},{"lon":"30.46398","lat":"50.50683"},{"lon":"30.46438","lat":"50.50611"},{"lon":"30.46451","lat":"50.50592"},{"lon":"30.46462","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46462","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46555","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46661","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.4668","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46704","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46732","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46777","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46807","lat":"50.50568"},{"lon":"30.46839","lat":"50.50573"},{"lon":"30.46878","lat":"50.50577"},{"lon":"30.4707","lat":"50.50604"},{"lon":"30.47168","lat":"50.50618"},{"lon":"30.47168","lat":"50.50618"},{"lon":"30.47184","lat":"50.50584"},{"lon":"30.47184","lat":"50.50584"},{"lon":"30.47138","lat":"50.50576"},{"lon":"30.47135","lat":"50.50576"}]
```

мне уже подсказали как вытащить первые две и последние две коодринаты

```
        $array = json_decode($json, true);
        /* На этом можно было бы закончить... */
        $from_start = array_slice($array, 0, 2); # 2 элемента, начиная с начала
        $from_end = array_slice($array, -2);     # 2 элемента, начиная с конца

        /* Формируем вывод, как нужно автору */
        foreach ($from_start as $k => $v) {
            $num = $k + 1;
            ${"coord{$num}_first_lon"} = $v['lon'];
            ${"coord{$num}_first_lat"} = $v['lat'];
        }
        foreach ($from_end as $k => $v) {
            $num = $k + 1;
            ${"coord{$num}_last_lon"} = $v['lon'];
            ${"coord{$num}_last_lat"} = $v['lat'];
        }
```

нашел также как найти расстояние между двумя координатами

```
$distance = 2 * asin(sqrt( pow(sin(deg2rad( ($lat1-$lat2) / 2)), 2) +cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) *pow(sin(deg2rad(($lng1- $lng2) / 2)), 2))) * 6378245;
```

вот запрос чтоб получить координаты данного маршрута в виде json строки

```
$json=mysql_query("SELECT coord FROM coords WHERE email='$email'");
```

а теперь мне нужно как-то это все связать в один механизм, че то пока не получается.
на выходе должно быть json -массив email ов маршруты которых близки к заданному

Comment: Какой-то не очень алгоритм Вы придумали.  
![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/nIVK5y9.png)
Маршрут **С** будет определен как ближний к **А**, чем **В**.

Comment: этого будет достаточно тут мне не нужна точность, мне нужно найти маршруты которые приблизительно находятся рядом или совпадают, точность тут не главное. просто поставлена именно такая задача что не важна точность вычислений, а просто чтоб какая-то приблизительная выборка формировалась

Answer (score 1):

Может быть заглянуть в книги, расстояние по Хеммингу, Чебышеву или Махалонобису высчитать, не? Поинтересоваться мерами близости, основанными на расстояниях и используемыми для принятия решений в алгоритмах кластеризации и классификации

Comment: 1)http://habrahabr.ru/post/101338/
2)http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/2265/243/lecture/6255

Comment: че-то как-то слишком умно. мне нужно попроще реализация. просто взять одну точку как ценрт окружности и потом смотреть какие из них попадют в этот центр

Comment: @Jenya  Kirmiza, не бывает в программировании "че-то как-то слишком умно". Алгоритмы специально разрабатываются для уменьшения затрат ресурсов и облегчения поиска.  
Если вам нужно посчитать точки в окружности, то это довольно легко делается через расчет расстояния до точки окружности: d = sqrt((x0 - x)^2 + (y0 - y)^2), та самая гипотенуза, чей квадрат равен сумме квадратов катетов. Просто отмечаете точки, у которых это расстояние меньше радиуса окружности - они-то и будут внутри нее.